# How do I create a private/internal virtual ip address?

Tags: azure, virtual-ip-address

I want to implement active/standby arrangement between 2 internal loadbalancer VMs (haproxy on each) via keepalived.  These loadbalancers are supposed to expose a private ip for use by other programs internal to my VPC.  How do I assign a virtual ip address to these nodes?

When I attempted to assign the same private ip address to the primary NICs of both nodes, I got an error message about a conflict when configuring the 2nd node.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assign same internal ip address to 2 different resources in azure. you need to assign internal ip address to the load balancer and make it route traffic to both of those 2 nodes.